# Saving crontab without exiting

Tags: cron

I ran `crontab -e`, made some edits, and did the usual `:w` to save, leaving the editor open. Coming back the next day, it appeared none of my changes had taken effect! Running `:wq` printed the message `crontab: installing new crontab`. Do I have to explicitly exit the crontab editor to install the new crontab, or is saving the file good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> -e
>
> Edits the current crontab using the editor specified by the
>   `VISUAL` or `EDITOR` environment variables.  After you exit from
>   the editor, the modified crontab will be installed
>   automatically.

From http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/crontab.1.html

So, yes, you need to exit the editor for `crontab -e` to take effect.